# Slider handle out of content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I dynamically create my JQuery slider like this:

```
var slider = document.createElement("div");
        $(slider).slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: "min",
        });
```

And assign him a class: `$(slider).slider().addClass("dhSliderDesktop");`
I also override some settings for the slider handle but cannot make it to fit it's track.
What am I doing worng? can you help please...

CSS:

```
.dhSliderDesktop {
    position: absolute !important;
    right:9px !important;
    visibility:hidden;
    height: 100% !important;

    width:10px !important;
    color:green !important;
    background-color:red !important;
    background: blue !important;} 



.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {

    width:40px !important;
    height:30px !important;

    left: -10.5px !important;
    border-style:none !important; 
    background-color: yellow !important;}
```

As you can see in the picture below the sliders handle is getting out of the content window which I don't want. How to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is play with:

```
    ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {  
    width: 40px !important;  
    height: 30px !important;  
    left: -10.5px !important;  
    ..
```

If you change those values you will change the slider's dimensions and position.

Comment: Yes I know. I used top:someValue to move the handle down but the it just stopped working

Comment: yes, you are not allowed to set any values for the direction the slider is oriented. Your slider is vertically so you are not allowed to set top or bottom. (actually you can set bottom as a default value, the slider will change the value of bottom when moving the slider, but don't set top value, it will make your slider to go back to the defined position. )

Comment: The easiest way is to set make the slider smaller and to set the  dhSliderDesktop height to something less the 100% ( like 80-90% )

Comment: Yes, but then the blue slider line wououn't be to the edges of the content.

Comment: But then, @Jacob, it looks like you're [building a slider scrollbar](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll) instead?

Comment: No I need a slider because it has to be vertical but with the same properties like a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses a wrapper div around the slider widget as a helper to display the full blue slider. The actual slider is centered within the wrapper, and I've used percentage values in an attempt to make the functionality independent of the outer wrapper size (but that still needs some css finetuning):

```
.slider-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    right: 10px;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position:absolute;
}
.slider-wrapper-range-min {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: red;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    position:absolute;
}
.dhSliderDesktop {
    height: 80% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: auto;
    border: none;
    background: blue !important;
    position: absolute;
} 

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {

    width:30px !important;
    height:24.5% !important;
    margin-bottom:-200%;
    margin-top: auto;

    left: -12px !important;
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

activated with the following jQuery code:

```
var $sliderWrapper = $('<div class="slider-wrapper"><div class="dhSliderDesktop"></div></div>');

$sliderWrapper
    .appendTo($(".wrapper"))
    .find(".dhSliderDesktop")
        .slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: "min",
            change: function(event,ui) {
                console.log(ui.value);
            }
        })
        .end()
    .append( $('<div class="slider-wrapper-range-min"></div>') )
;
```

**Edit:** Here's an updated [**link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/2kaqf/5/)

Comment: Is there maybe a way to modify the Jwuery CSS directly

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be to intercept the slider change event and adjust the location of the handler as needed
Example code:

```
  $("#Slider1").slider({
          change: function (event, ui) {
            var TempID = $(this).attr('id');
            var LeftVal = $("#" + TempID).find("a").css("left"); 
            if (LeftVal == "500px") $("#" + TempID).find("a").css("left", "485px");
        }
    });
```

The code above assumes that your slider width is 500px and your handler image is 30px. We subtracted 15px from the hanlder left css style.